# Why am I receiving "This page isn't working HTTP ERROR 500" after installing CiviRules?

Tags: civicrm-home, civirules

I am interested in using CiviRules to automate some processes within CiviCRM.  I am using CiviCRM 4.6.6 and installed CiviRules 2.4.  When I went to add a rule clicking Next from the first CiviRules Add Rule page I am directed to a page displaying "This page isn't working  *mysite* is currently unable to handle this request.  HTTP ERROR 500".  I receive the same error page when I attempt to "cleanup the cache" and any other process I have tested.  Everything returns to normal after I uninstall CiviRules.  Anyone know how I can fix this?  All help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to CiviCRM.SE. A 500 error is a very generic error indicating that the web server encountered a problem; to see what that problem is, you need to look in the logs. Can you [edit] your post to include the backtrace?

Comment: Also, what version of PHP are you running?

Comment: Currently running php 5.3.3

Comment: I turned back trace and error logging on but I have no ideas how to find these logs.

Comment: See https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/troubleshooting/